# Find Indefinite of root function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I don't know how to find this strange integral

$\int{\sqrt{\dfrac{x-4}{x+2}}\dfrac{dx}{x+2}}$

Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Set $$\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+2}}=t, \frac{x-4}{x+2}=t^2,t^2-1=\frac{-6}{x+2}, x+2=\frac6{1-t^2}$$

Comment: I think formular for 1 + t^2 is wrong

Comment: @phuong, please find the edited version